# Simple LED display project not printing to the console how I want it to

Tags: python

I've been tasked with creating a simple LED display that allows a user to input any non-negative integer and will print that number onto the console. I'm still learning and there are most likely better ways to do this but here's the code I came up with:

```
num = input('enter a number: ')

for i in num:

    if i == '1':
        row1 = '  #'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '  #'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '  #'

        fullnum1 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum1)
        

    elif i == '2':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '#  '
        row5 = '###'

        fullnum2 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum2)


    elif i == '3':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '###'

        fullnum3 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum3)


    elif i == '4':
        row1 = '# #'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '  #'

        fullnum4 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum4)


    elif i == '5':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '#  '
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '###'

        fullnum5 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum5)


    elif i == '6':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '#  '
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '# #'
        row5 = '###'

        fullnum6 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum6)


    elif i == '7':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '  #'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '  #'

        fullnum7 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum7)


    elif i == '8':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '# #'
        row5 = '###'

        fullnum8 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum8)


    elif i == '9':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '###'

        fullnum9 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum9)


    elif i == '0':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '# #'
        row4 = '# #'
        row5 = '###'

        fullnum0 = f' {row1} \n {row2} \n {row3} \n {row4} \n {row5} \n'
        ls.append(fullnum0)
        

for i in ls:
    print(i)
```

When the code is run, it prints the input vertically instead of each number side-by-side. I've tried this:

```
for i in num:
        print(i, end='')
```

But it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't just automatically print two things side by side like that, you'd have to concatenate the rows of each number together and print them one at a time until you reach the last row. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. Will that require a complete restructuring of the code here?

Comment: Yes - When you print the numbers, you need to print the first row of each number, then the second row, etc... If you store each number as a list of strings, that may be easier.

Answer (score 1):

For a more compact version, you can create the number lists in one line then split the line:

```
all = '''
  # ### ### # # ### ### ### ### ### ### 
  #   #   # # # #   #     # # # # # # # 
  # ### ### ### ### ###   # ### ### # # 
  # #     #   #   # # #   # # #   # # # 
  # ### ###   # ### ###   # ### ### ### 
'''[1:-1]

dnum = {}
keys = '1234567890'
for k in keys:
   dnum[k] = []
lines = all.split('\n')
for ln in lines:
   for i,k in enumerate(keys):
       dnum[k].append(ln[i*4:i*4+4])

def shownum(num):
   for r in range(5):  # 5 rows tall
      for n in num:
         print(dnum[n][r], end='') # each digit
      print()  # next row

num = input('enter a number: ')
while num != '':
    shownum(num)
    num = input('enter a number: ')
```

Output

```
enter a number: 123
  # ### ###
  #   #   #
  # ### ###
  # #     #
  # ### ###

enter a number: 987
### ### ###
# # # #   #
### ###   #
  # # #   #
### ###   #
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what you want:

```
# Create a dictionary, mapping each input character to an LED display representation
nums={
    '0':[
    "###",
    "# #",
    "# #",
    "# #",
    "###"
    ],
    '1':[
    "  #",
    "  #",
    "  #",
    "  #",
    "  #"
    ],
    '2':[
    "###",
    "  #",
    "###",
    "#  ",
    "###"
    ],
    '3':[
    "###",
    "  #",
    "###",
    "  #",
    "###"
    ],
    '4':[
    "# #",
    "# #",
    "###",
    "  #",
    "  #"
    ],
    '5':[
    "###",
    "#  ",
    "###",
    "  #",
    "###"
    ],
    '6':[
    "###",
    "#  ",
    "###",
    "# #",
    "###"
    ],
    '7':[
    "###",
    "  #",
    "  #",
    "  #",
    "  #"
    ],
    '8':[
    "###",
    "# #",
    "###",
    "# #",
    "###"
    ],
    '9':[
    "###",
    "# #",
    "###",
    "  #",
    "###"
    ]
}

while True:
    input_num=input("enter a number: ")
    print_str=""
    for i in range(5):  # because there are 5 rows per number
        for num in input_num:  # we have to fully build each row, so each input number has to be looped through
            print_str += nums[num][i] + "   "  # add a space separator between digits
        print_str += "\n"  # start the next row
    print(print_str)  # output the result at the end
```

Output:

```
enter a number: 56372
###   ###   ###   ###   ###   
#     #       #     #     #   
###   ###   ###     #   ###   
  #   # #     #     #   #     
###   ###   ###     #   ###   

enter a number: 12345
  #   ###   ###   # #   ###   
  #     #     #   # #   #     
  #   ###   ###   ###   ###   
  #   #       #     #     #   
  #   ###   ###     #   ###   

enter a number: 00101
###   ###     #   ###     #   
# #   # #     #   # #     #   
# #   # #     #   # #     #   
# #   # #     #   # #     #   
###   ###     #   ###     #
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. Others have posted solutions which are great. Here's mine if anyone's interested.

```
firstline = []
secondline = []
thirdline = []
fourthline =[]
fifthline = []

def concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline):
    firstline.append(row1)
    secondline.append(row2)
    thirdline.append(row3)
    fourthline.append(row4)
    fifthline.append(row5)


num = input('enter a number: ')

for i in num:

    if i == '1':
        row1 = '  #'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '  #'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '  #'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)
        
    elif i == '2':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '#  '
        row5 = '###'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '3':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '###'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '4':
        row1 = '# #'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '  #'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '5':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '#  '
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '###'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '6':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '#  '
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '# #'
        row5 = '###'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '7':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '  #'
        row3 = '  #'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '  #'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '8':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '# #'
        row5 = '###'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '9':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '###'
        row4 = '  #'
        row5 = '###'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)

    elif i == '0':
        row1 = '###'
        row2 = '# #'
        row3 = '# #'
        row4 = '# #'
        row5 = '###'

        concatenate_lines(firstline, secondline, thirdline, fourthline, fifthline)


new1 = ' '.join(firstline)
new2 = ' '.join(secondline)
new3 = ' '.join(thirdline)
new4 = ' '.join(fourthline)
new5 = ' '.join(fifthline)

print(new1)
print(new2)
print(new3)
print(new4)
print(new5)
```

It has more lines compared to other solutions but I tried to keep it very readable.